# Resizing the last layer of an CNN for Segmantic Segmentation fails on GPU but works on CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I currently try to train a CNN for segmantic segmentation. In a paper i read that increasing (resampling) the image input can help to increase the performance. In this paper they propose to increase the input image size by bilinear resampling and then reducing it back to the original image size in the last layer of the network. The images are of size (256,256,3) and i want to resize them to (384,384,3)

I tried to implement this using tensorflows "Resizing layer"(https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Resizing). This works perfectly fine when i run the code on CPU. However, when i try training the network on GPU, i get an out of memory error. When i look at the error message, it says that the layer tried to resize the image to (Batch_Size, 256,384,384) in channels first mode) or to (BatchSize,384,384,256) in channels last mode. It seems that the resizing layer (which is actually proposed to be a "preprocessing layer") cant resize the image properly and confuses the shapes and dimensions.

Has anyone faced this problem and nows how to solve it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.